# Which Google API can access Hangouts Data?

Tags: google-apps, google-hangouts, google-reporting-api

What Google API would be the easiest to father the following information:

- A list of all hangouts currently going on in my Google for Work Organization
- People in those Hangouts
- Links to join those hangouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the link below maybe could help.
It provides basic information such as getting the list of participants, getting the URL for the Hangout, and getting the HangoutId.

https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/gapi.hangout#gapi.hangout.getHangoutId